# How to get the result of 3 linked tables for patient coverage

Tags: sql

In my app, the user will enter the patient id and medicine needed (from Doctor). My code needs to check whether this patient's insurance will cover the medicine. This comes from a linkage of several tables: I just want the end result, enter patient id and see if the order is accepted. What sort of query will work here?

OEN_FED_M_RXNORM maps GCN_SEQNO codes to the RXCUI code (nds master has the gcn_seqno code)

```
                GCN_SEQNO Numeric(6, 0)
                RXCUI Varchar(8)
```

OEN_FED_M_PARTD_PLAN maps the plan to a formulary code (patient record has the plan code)

```
                    CONTRACT_ID                  Char(5)
                    PLAN_ID                      Char(3)
                    SEGMENT_ID                   Char(3)
                    MA_REGION_CODE               Char(2)
                    PDP_REGION_CODE              Char(2)
                    FORMULARY_ID                 Char(8)
                    DC_DATE                      DATETIME
                    CONTRACT_NAME                VARCHAR(50)
                    PLAN_NAME                    VARCHAR(100)
                    PREMIUM                      NUMERIC (6,2)
                    DEDUCTABLE                   NUMERIC (6,0)
                    ICL                          NUMERIC (6,0)
                    SMP                          CHAR(1)
                    PLAN_SUPPRESSED_YN           CHAR(1)
```

OEN_FED_D_BASIC_FORMULARY combines the formulary code and RXCUI code to get the coverage.

```
                     FORMULARY_ID             CHAR(8)
                     FORMULARY_VERSION        NUMERIC(3,0)
                     CONTRACT_YEAR            CHAR(4)
                     RXCUI                    CHAR(6)
                     START_DATE               DATETIME
                     DC_DATE                  DATETIME
                     PROXY_NDC                CHAR(11)
                     TIER_LEVEL_VALUE         NUMERIC(2,0)
                     QUANTITY_LIMIT_YN        CHAR(1,0)
                     QUANTITY_LIMIT_AMOUNT    NUMERIC(8,4)
                     QUANTITY_LIMIT_DAYS      NUMERIC(6,0)
```

Comment: Your first table has the same column name twice. Should that second field be "RXCUI"?

Comment: Also, which is the driving (parent) table? Is it OEN_FED_M_PARTD_PLAN joins to OEN_FED_M_RXNORM which in turn joins to OEN_FED_D_BASIC_FORMULARY?

Comment: The residents drug ndc is mapped to the GCN_SEQNO
That is mapped to the RXCUI
The residents Part D plan is mapped to a formulary ID
The formulaty ID together with the date and rxcui get the coverage status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a start. Just put the fields you need in the SELECT.

```
SELECT *
FROM   oen_fed_m_rxnorm rxnorm
       INNER JOIN oen_fed_d_basic_formulary formulary ON (rxnorm.rxcui = formulary.rxcui)
       INNER JOIN oen_fed_m_partd_plan ON (plan.formulary_id = formulary.formulary_id)
WHERE  rxnorm.gcn_seqno = [your residents drug ndcs]
```